# Javascript canvas draw from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I am currently creating a family tree and have run into some problems when creating the children nodes coming from the father node. At the moment I am drawing `topPerson.draw(context);` which = the father node and then calling a for loop to cycle through an array of children they have which exists in the Partnership.js file, the array is `this.mChildren = new Array();`

What I am trying to do is cycle through the array and draw each child underneath the parent node in the same style as the parent (bordered with rectangle, image centered and name underneath).

The Person.js which is used to set the origin of canvas to center, draw a rectangle, write text including name of the node and then add node image:

```
Person.prototype.draw = function (context) {
    //draw rectangle
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
    context.scale(1, 1);
    context.rect(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5,160,210);
    context.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.font = "30px Arial";
    context.fillText(this.getName(), canvas.width * 0.5 + 15, canvas.height * 0.5 + 190);
    //get image and draw
    context.drawImage(this.getImage(), canvas.width * 0.5 + 5, canvas.height * 0.5 + 5);
```

I have tried to create an array that looks like this:

```
for (i = 0; < mChildren.length; i++){
        img = new Image();
        img.src = mChildren[i];
        img.onLoad = (function(img, i){
            return function () {
                context.drawImage(img, i*img.width, i*img.height);
            }
        })(img, i)
    }
```

Comment: So cycle through your array with a loop and call `.draw` on each of them. Just avoid clearing the canvas and simply draw the item in your method.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i am doing a for loop by saying `for (i = 0; < mChildren.length; i++){` and then theres a set of functions such as getChild, numChilds and addChild, would I then do `getChild.draw`?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to iterate over an array and draw a tree then I would suggest using D3 here is a heap  structure i made using D3 https://youtu.be/bFz3sdR3EFI . If what you want to create is anything similar at all then I can help you out by writing out an a modified example of what I did, to fit better to your design.

Comment: @Pete thanks for the link Pete but I have to use canvas and an array in order to create a family tree with children and partner nodes coming from the original node, thats basically what I am looking to do. So I have an array of children I need to iterate through then draw onto the canvas.

Comment: @Douglas, that's what D3 does it uses a canvas that allows it to create and add SVG elements. Draw a simple mockup of the layout and I will help you out. Also how would you in the array plan on deciding the hierarchy?

Comment: @Pete I can simply explain what I am looking for. I have one Parent node drawn onto the canvas, coming off of that should be their children and any partners they have. This is all stored in an array. Once the images have been taken from the array, I shall use `.translate` to place them accordingly on the canvas

Comment: @Pete if its also of any help, I can send the full code to you or we can work on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yes, because I have no idea what functions you are using or what part you're at, so yes, but it in JS fiddle.

Comment: @Pete http://jsfiddle.net/pxods2og/#&togetherjs=JyoIS7cBQ9

Comment: @Pete added my code to jsfiddle at the link above, join that link and we shall go over it